# How does Debug.WriteLine send messages to output window

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, diagnostics

In other words I'm wondering how communication process is going on between visual studio and application launched in debug mode. 
I guess one of the trace listeners writes messages to a file and visual studio reads that file all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls the Win32 API function [`OutputDebugString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx), which the debugger (Visual Studio) can listen for.

See the [corresponding source in .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0aa1e7697fb66057ed4f0be1b93e9adccd1b8c5/src/Common/src/System/Diagnostics/Debug.Windows.cs), for example.

Comment: You answer makes next question - How does visual studio listen for that function calls? :) I will try to figure out it.